# Unable to view plots on GitHub using md file

Tags: r, github, r-markdown

I created a R markdown file on R Studio [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpdHD.jpg) and used the Knit function to create an html file. Eventually, .md file and html files were created in my working directory. Also, a figures folder/directory was created automatically. And hence, I pushed all the changes made to my GitHub repository.

Now, my problem here is when I open the .md (markdown) file on GitHub, it doesn't view the plots
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4tol.jpg)

Comment: Could you share the link to your GitHub repo?

Comment: https://github.com/itz-krizz/Reproducible-Research-Week-2

Comment: i dont know what i m missing here if you know something please help me out

Comment: Is this still an issue or did you find your solution?

Answer (score 2):

You have to [push images](https://github.com/itz-krizz/Reproducible-Research-Week-2/pull/1) to the GitHub repo. Images cannot be viewed because they are missing.